# I am creating a copy activity in Azure Data Factory with Auto Create Table. The columns DataType and Nullable are changing

Tags: azure-data-factory

When performing copy activity with auto create table. Then few columns like DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE are mismatched when compared between source and target.

[image: Comparison between source and target]

Comment: could you please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/137145/azure-data-factory-column-value-not-flowing-throug.html and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response @UtkarshPal-MT
Since I am performing copy activity with auto create table. Is it taking as NULLS by defaults? I am not getting any errors the data is loading but the columns IS_NULLABLE and the DATA_TYPE are changing. Is it possible using copy activity without the data flow?

Comment: Could you plz provide the following details for better understanding:
1. What are source and sink dataset types?
2. Sample source data 
3. If source dataset is file then file format

Comment: source is sql db and sink is on-premise sql db.

Comment: Source :-
  
TableName ColumnName IS_Nullable Data_Type
Employee EmpID No Integer
Employee EmpName No Varchar(100)
Employee Salary No Numeric(2,2)
Employee DeptID No Integer
Employee DeptName No Varchar(100)

Comment: Target :-
  
TableName ColumnName IS_Nullable Data_Type
Employee EmpID Yes Integer
Employee EmpName Yes Varchar(100)
Employee Salary Yes Decimal
Employee DeptID Yes Integer
Employee DeptName Yes Varchar(100)

Comment: Yes, you can use copy activity without the data flow.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing and it’s working fine for me. You can follow the same steps as shown below:

Firstly, you must create the source and sink databases. Follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-quickstart?tabs=azure-portal) to create Azure SQL Database.

You then have to create the Linked Service for source database in ADF.
[image]

Similarly, create the Linked Service for on-premises Sink database. Follow [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5812/connect-to-onpremises-data-in-azure-data-factory-with-the-selfhosted-integration-runtime--part-1/).

Create the Source Dataset using source database Linked Service created above.
[image]

Similarly, create the sink dataset using sink database linked service.
[image]

Finally, you need to create the pipeline using copy activity, source dataset, sink dataset. Optionally, you can do mapping of the columns. Refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping) to know more about mapping.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Below are my Source and Copied Datasets after running the pipeline. Both are same as expected.
[image: Source Dataset]
[image: Copied Dataset]

Please do follow the shared steps.